# Cross domain Authentication

Tags: asp.net

Client have a site built using Wordpress.  We have built a web app for them in asp.net on a subdomain.  Client now wants a login to the .net web app on the homepage of their wordpress site.
Obviously this needs to be secure.

How would this cross domain auth usually be performed?

Can it be done in an iframe or is some other method preferred>

Thanks

Wing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iFrame could do the trick but the elegant way of doing this would be using JSON data to communicate between different domains. You must be able to modify your client's wordpress site (authentication part of it) which would send a JSON object to your asp.net application.

Then your asp.net application should decide whether the login should be successful or not looking at the JSON data sent by wordpress site. Good luck